# Which Model Statement to use in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am very new to MVC 3 framework.  I have added an Entity with the EntityFramework 6.0, and in my controller, I would like to query the entity for all "DeviceInterfaces" which belong to a particular device.  My view is throwing this error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `` System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType1`2[System.String,System.String]] ``, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `` System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FindDevice.DeviceInterfaces] ``.

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult DeviceName(string name)
    {
SampleEntities sampleEntities = new SampleEntities();

        try
        {
            var Model = (from dev in sampleEntities.NetworkDevices
                         where dev.Name == name
                         from inter in sampleEntities.DeviceInterfaces
                         where inter.NetworkDevice.Id == dev.Id
                         //select inter);
                         select new { DeviceName = dev.Name, InterfaceName = inter.Name});
            return View(Model);
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return View();
    }
```

My View:

```
    @model IEnumerable<FindDevice.DeviceInterfaces>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DeviceName";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Displaying Device with name "@ViewBag.MyName"</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Device</th>
    <th>Interface</th>
    <th>IPv4 Address</th>
    <th>Subnet Mask</th>
    <th>CIDR</th>
    <th>Network</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>item.NetworkDevice.Name</td>
    <td>@item.Name</td>
    <td>@item.IPv4Address</td>
    <td>@item.IPv4SubnetMask</td>
    <td>@item.CIDR</td>
    <td>@item.Subnet</td>
</tr>
}
```

I understand why the error is thrown, what I don't understand is what I can change my `@model` statement to so that I can display the Device Name, as well as the Interface Name and all other interface properties in this view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a strongly typed model. Add the below class in `Models` folder

```
public class DeviceInterfaceModel
{
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string InterfaceName { get; set; }
    public string IPv4Address { get; set; }
    public string IPv4SubnetMask { get; set; }
    public string CIDR { get; set; }
    public string Subnet { get; set; }
}
```

Then map the query results to a `List<DeviceInterfaceModel>` in your controller

```
public ActionResult DeviceName(string name)
{
    SampleEntities sampleEntities = new SampleEntities();

    try
    {
        var model = (from dev in sampleEntities.NetworkDevices
                     where dev.Name == name
                     from inter in sampleEntities.DeviceInterfaces
                     where inter.NetworkDevice.Id == dev.Id
                     select new DeviceInterfaceModel
                     { 
                         DeviceName = dev.Name, 
                         InterfaceName = inter.Name,
                         IPv4Address = inter.IPv4Address,
                         IPv4SubnetMask = inter.IPv4SubnetMask,
                         CIDR = inter.CIDR,
                         Subnet = inter.Subnet
                     }).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    return View();
}
```

and change the model type to `IEnumerable<DeviceInterfaceModel>` in your view

```
@model IEnumerable<DeviceInterfaceModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DeviceName";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Displaying Device with name "@ViewBag.MyName"</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Device</th>
    <th>Interface</th>
    <th>IPv4 Address</th>
    <th>Subnet Mask</th>
    <th>CIDR</th>
    <th>Network</th>
</tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>@item.DeviceName</td>
    <td>@item.InterfaceName</td>
    <td>@item.IPv4Address</td>
    <td>@item.IPv4SubnetMask</td>
    <td>@item.CIDR</td>
    <td>@item.Subnet</td>
</tr>
}
```